# Как скачать картинку?

Tags: java

Есть вот такой url на картинку:
`https://testrail.ru/index.php?/attachments/get/400605`
и её не получается сохранить, других урлов нет, но другие картинки, где указан точный урл до нее, (например `https://sun9-61.userapi.com/c7004/v7004863/6d7bd/UjMTR0jHvSI.jpg`) то она скачивается спокойно, если открыть файл через блокнот, то файл пустой
мой код:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String url =
                "https://testrail.ru/index.php?/attachments/get/400605"
                ;
        final URLConnection hpCon = new URL(url).openConnection();
        final int len = hpCon.getContentLength();
        if (len > 0) {
            /* read data */
            final byte[] imageData = new byte[len];
            final InputStream inputStream = ((URLConnection) hpCon).getInputStream();
            try {
                int readed = 0;
                do {
                    readed += inputStream.read(imageData, readed, len - readed);
                } while(readed < len);
            } finally {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            /* write data */
            final OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("zwischen123.jpg");
            try {
                outputStream.write(imageData);
            } finally {
                try {
                    outputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        } else {
            System.out.println("Net sodergimogo ili no connection");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Не могу вообще ничего получить по такому url в хроме. Он кстати судя по всему неправильный. Не может быть пути после `?`. Только параметры запроса. Может ты имел в виду `https://testrail.ru/attachments/get/400605`?

Comment: @maklas, через vpn компании в которой я работаю можно получить))

Comment: А точно URL правильный? Впервые вижу такой. Возможно есть разница как его энтерпретируют браузеры и Java

Comment: урл точно верный
дело в том, что нет указания названия файла, просто его айдишник в урле

Comment: если бы был доступ, думаю помог бы. Опыт есть. А так могу только посоветовать. Откройте в хроме и посмотрите как идёт взаимодействие с сайтом через админ-панель. Какие хидеры приходят. Может там редирект? Может быть нужно быть залогиненым? vpn? Js? Придётся разбираться самому)

Comment: Вообще похоже, что это не путь к картинке, а путь к attachment. По похожему принципу сделано в jira. Попробуйте открыть именно картинку... возможно через "Открыть картинку в новой вкладке" или сделайте инспект в chrome и убедитесь, что это не врапер.

Comment: Открыл картинку в новой вкладке, url: `https://testrail.ru/index.php?/attachments/get/400605`
body:
`<img style="-webkit-user-select: none;margin: auto;cursor: zoom-in;" src="https://testrail.ru/index.php?/attachments/get/400605" width="741" height="417">`